# List all valid Ipv4Addr on host

Tags: sockets, udp, rust, multicast, igmp

I need to send the same multicast UDP packet on all available addresses on my host. I need to send to `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` and `239.255.0.1`. Rust's `std` lib has deprecated multicast behavior since version 1.2, and anyway, to get the specificity I need I have to switch to the more complete `net2`.

The `net2` API has a bunch of [UDP extensions](http://alexcrichton.com/net2-rs/net2/trait.UdpSocketExt.html) which provide the API I'm looking for. I'm specifically interested in

```
fn join_multicast_v4(&self, multiaddr: &Ipv4Addr, interface: &Ipv4Addr) -> Result<()>
```

But I can't figure out what to do for multiaddr vs interface. I thought I would just give the multiaddr `127.0.0.1` or `239.255.0.1` but how do I find the valid IPv4's for the `interface` parameter? Is there a Rust function, somewhere out there, that can provide a `Vec<Ipv4Addr>`? Do I need to parse the output of `ifconfig`?

Here is a stand-alone program which sends out my public interface (had to find that `192.168.0.102` address by hand):

```
extern crate net2;

use std::net::{ UdpSocket, Ipv4Addr };
use net2::UdpSocketExt;

fn main() {
  let sock = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:2345").unwrap();
  let local_addr = Ipv4Addr::new(192, 168, 0, 102);
  let multicast_addr = Ipv4Addr::new(239, 255, 0, 1);

  sock.join_multicast_v4(&multicast_addr, &local_addr).unwrap();
}
```

I'm compiling on nightlies if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you mean bind to local interface?

Comment: I think there's a distinction to be made when saying "bind to a local interface". I'm not only trying to bind to "loopback", but to all interfaces on the machine running the code.